# Motivation and Intuition of Yukawa interaction term

Tags: field-theory, interactions, intuition

Let's consider the Lagrangian density for Scalar Yukawa theory:
$$
\mathcal L = \partial_\mu \psi^\ast \partial^{\mu} \psi - M^2 \psi^\ast \psi + \frac12 \left(\partial_\mu \phi \partial^{\mu} \phi -m^2 \phi^2 \right) - g\psi^\ast \psi \phi. 
$$

What is the motivation/intuition for suggesting the form of the last interaction term $- g\psi^\ast \psi \phi$?

I searched for a while, but apparently, this *seems* to be pretty fundamental and cannot be "derived". So are there any simple ways to show that, for example, this term resembles some familiar objects in quantum/classical mechanics?

Comment: You know how to couple photons to spinors, Lorentz invariantly. How would you couple scalars?

Answer (score 0):

When writing down the Lagrangian you want to write all the Lorentz invariant terms and if you want to have a renormalizable theory then you stop at terms with coupling constant with mass dimension zero $[g]=0$. So you found the mass terms with coupling constant $[m^2]=2$ and $[M]=1$ (note that it should be $M \psi^* \psi$).
Since a Lorentz invariant term with spinor is $\psi^* \psi$ and the scalar is a scalar so it can enter as $\phi$, let us count the mass dimension:

$$[\psi \psi^*]=3 \quad [\phi] = 1 \rightarrow [g]=0$$

So if you add other terms with a higher power of $\psi$ or $\phi$ than you get non-renormalizable terms (that are ok but the "most important" term is the one you wrote above)